# Alt characters can't be typed in textarea when used with bootstrap's modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using bootstrap modal dialog. The dialog has a simple textarea and a button.

**Issue:**

When I switch the keyboard input to Indian languages like Hindi. Characters that are typed with Alt cannot be typed instead they point to shortcuts of firefox.

```js
$("#open").click(function(){
$("#feedbackdialog").modal();
    $('#feedbackdialog').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
            $("#fdtext").focus();
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <button id="open" class="btn btn-default">
  open
  </button>
  <div id="feedbackdialog" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Comment</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="active" id="segtab">
                                                <div align="center" class="form group row">
                                                        <textarea id="fdtext" class="form-control form-group" placeholder="Sentence Comment here"></textarea>
                                                        <button id="savefdb" class="btn">OK</button>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

For information, I found this issue in firefox52.0.2

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>alt</kbd> + numbers will result in switching shortcuts of firefox.

You can try pressing on <kbd>ALT+SHIFT</kbd> instead of <kbd>ALT</kbd> only.

Also you can refer to this firefox plug-in that called [**Key config**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/key-config/). This add-on provides configurable keyboard shortcuts for several actions and a dialog to customize them.

i hope it helps you, thanks.

Comment: when alt is pressed focus is not on textarea at all, whether you use alt+shift or alt+anycharacter.